# R removes more observations than it should with dplyr or base subset

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I've got a question regarding the filter() function of dplyr, and/or base subset() function within R. Basically, when I use filter() or subset() I can extract observations based on two conditions, which is what I need. 
As an example, this is what I've been using so far:

```
df %>% filter(Axis_1_1 == "Diagnostic of function on axis1 postponed") %>% filter(is.na(diagnostic_code9))
```

This gives me the right amount of observations that satisfy these two conditions at the same time, i.e. 92 out of the 23992 in total.

However, when I use the negation sign to not include these observations in my current dataframe, R is deleting roughly 8000 extra observations. Thus, the end result is 15992 observations left after filtering with the negation "!" sign used. Example:

```
df %>% filter(Axis_1_1 != "Diagnostic of function on axis1 postponed") %>% filter(!is.na(diagnostic_code9))
```

Using simple subsetting from base R gives me the same wrong end result, while it manages to find the correct 92 observations that satisfy the condition, as stated in the first example.

```
subset(df, df$Axis1_1 == "Diagnostic of function on axis1 postponed" & is.na(diagnostic_code9))
```

My dataframe consists of 112 variables and 23900+ observations in the current setting.

Thus, my questions are:

- Could there be something curious going on with my dataframe I'm using (Unfortunately I cannot give you a subset out of it)
- Second, is there something wrong here with my coding?
- Lastly, what is R exactly doing in the background? Since it is able to filter out these observations based on the exact conditioning where they match the string and is.na() function, while doing completely something else when using the negation sign.

Comment: In logic, you are doing `A AND B`  the first time, and `(not A) AND (not B)` the second time. But `not(A AND B)` is actually `(not A) OR (not B)`. See [deMorgan's Laws on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: So what you want the second time to get the complement is `filter(Axis_1_1 != "Diagnostic of function on axis1 postponed" | !is.na(diagnostic_code9))`.

Comment: Or, if you used a single `filter` with `filter(A & B)` the first time you could negate it with parentheses `filter(!(A & B))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic doesn't quote work in this case. Doing two subsequent filter statments is kind of like doing an AND operation. Consider the following example

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2, 2), 
                 b=c(NA,NA,5,5,5,5,5,NA))    

df %>% filter(a==1) %>% filter(is.na(b))
#   a  b
# 1 1 NA
# 2 1 NA
df %>% filter(a!=1) %>% filter(!is.na(b))
#   a b
# 1 2 5
# 2 2 5
# 3 2 5
```

Note the rows with a=1, b=5 are not returned even though they are not in the first output because your first filter (`filter(!=1)`) eliminates them.

So if you consider your two filters as A and B, in the first case you are doing A and B. It would be the same as

```
df %>% filter(a==1 & is.na(b))
#   a  b
# 1 1 NA
# 2 1 NA
```

But in the second you are doing NOT A and NOT B. These are not equivalent. According to [DeMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), you need NOT A OR NOT B. So try

```
df %>% filter(a!=1 | !is.na(b))
#   a  b
# 1 1  5
# 2 1  5
# 3 2  5
# 4 2  5
# 5 2  5
# 6 2 NA
```

or equivalently (note the parenthsis applying the NOT (`!`) to the whole expression)

```
df %>% filter(!(a==1 & is.na(b)))
```

Comment: Nice answer ;)  Might be worth finding/making a canonical dupe for this.

Comment: @Gregor Yes. I see there is lots of overlap with your comments :) If you find other questions like this, it would make sense to combine.

Comment: [Not as many hits as I thought](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+is%3Aanswer+de+morgan). I wasn't thorough, but after looking at a couple I like this answer the best. I might start closing others as a dupe of this one.

Comment: The posted solutions both worked. Thanks for the clarification with DeMorgans law, something I haven't thought about deeply enough. However, in the case of NOT A OR NOT B, I presumed that it was always the case of NOT A AND  NOT B, since I want to filter out rows where both columns satisfy a certain value (be it NA or a string) at the same time.